# Sorting in SSRS on Detail View

Tags: excel, sorting, visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I'm asking on behalf of a coworker for this question.

She is using Visual Studio 2012/SQL Server 2012.

In EXCEL how you can sort easily from A-Z, Z-A and stuff of the sort in real time, is there a way to be able to do that in SSRS? Say a user drills from main view into detail view...is there a way with the info they can sort/mess around with it prior to exporting to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.. Click on the header line for the column that you want to sort.. right click - Text Box Properties - Interactive Sorting then choose the Enable Interactive Sorting on this text box and then choose which field you want to sort by... when you run the report.. you will get an arrow next to the header that you can click to sort.. you can do this on multiple columns.. and if you wanted to sort by more than one column... you sort it by clicking on column one.. hold down shift and then the next column.. done.. the arrows do not print or export.. it's visible only on interactive view.